# Converting MBR to GPT because of dual-boot

Tags: debian, dual-boot, gpt, mbr

yesterday I installed debian on my system. It all went relatively smooth and nice. Today I decided to install Windows 10 alongside Debian.
Unluckily W10 wants a GPT partition table, and Debian installed a MBR (probably asked me if it was ok, I didn't know about the GPT thing...).
So I went ahead and converted the partition table on my disk using gdisk.
I successfully installed windows, there is a new entry on my motherboard "bios" called Windows Boot Manager or something like that, if I set that as first in the boot order, windows starts ok.
Now I'd like my Debian back.
I'm writing this from a Debian live usb, and my disk partition table now looks like this:

```
root@debian:~# gdisk /dev/sdb
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.10

Partition table scan:
 MBR: protective
 BSD: not present
 APM: not present
 GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

Command (? for help): p
Disk /dev/sdb: 234441648 sectors, 111.8 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): C30CDFBB-EBFD-4E01-AB9B-31F60867035C
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 234441614
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2925 sectors (1.4 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
 1            2048       112429055   53.6 GiB    8300  Linux filesystem
 2       112429056       113350655   450.0 MiB   2700  Basic data partition
 3       113350656       113555455   100.0 MiB   EF00  EFI system partition
 4       113555456       113588223   16.0 MiB    0C01  Microsoft reserved ...
 5       113588224       224862207   53.1 GiB    0700  Basic data partition
 6       224862208       234440703   4.6 GiB     8200  Linux swap
```

I think partition 2 is the Windows Recovery (?) and partition 3 was created by Windows too, maybe that's the "windows boot manager" I find in my motherboard boot settings, but I don't know really.
Can you suggest how to proceed from here, possibly without wiping out debian nor windows?

Answer (score 1):

Your linux bootmanager (grub2) has been overwritten by the windows bootloader. The windows bootloader doesn't support booting linux, but grub2 does support booting both. With grub you get a selection menu on boot.
(Next time install windows first, then debian!)

You need to boot linux (debian) from CD/DVD/USB and chroot you linux partitions. Reinstall or update grub to make it work again.

Here is a link howto (for ubuntu which should work for debian, too):
http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd

good luck!